# Toshiba satellite r830 won't start, only orange flashing power symbol

Tags: laptop, power

My Satellite R830 won't turn on.

The power symbol flashes orange 8 times then pauses and restarts. there are 6 quick flashes followed by a longer one on the 7th flash then another quick one. The wireless symbol is lit up (orange) all the time.

If I unplug the laptop and take out the battery and hold the restart button for 30s then without the battery plug in the charger the flashing stops and the power symbol goes green, until I try turning it on, it has a split second where it sounds like it's booting up then stops and the orange flashing resumes.

Same thing happens if I unplug the ac adaptor and the battery and then tried the above but with the battery and no ac charger.

I have tried with another adaptor (same amp and voltage output).

Answer (score 0):

Source [Toshiba R830-S8310 User's Manual: Monitoring Main Battery Power](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/203424/Toshiba-R830-S8310.html?page=122)

> The computer's main battery light gives you an indication of the main
>   battery's current charge.
>
> - Glows amber while the main battery is being charged (AC adaptor connected)
> - Glows green when the main battery is fully charged
> - Is unlit when the battery has discharged, the battery is not charging, or the AC adaptor is not plugged into the computer or AC
>     outlet
> - Flashes amber when the main battery charge is low and it is time to recharge the main battery or plug in the AC adaptor
>
> If the AC power light **flashes amber during charging**, either a battery pack is malfunctioning, or it is not receiving correct input
>   from the AC power supply. Disconnect the AC power cord/cable and
>   remove the battery pack.

**Toshiba Technical Support**

For technical support, call the Toshiba Customer Support Center:

- Within the United States at (800) 457-7777
- Outside the United States at (949) 859-4273

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't explain why it won't turn on. From what I've read this is an error code, but I don't understand why it is happening for both the charger and the battery. If I take out the battery it sounds like starts to boot up, same thing if I remove the battery and only use the charger.